# Multiple producers consumers with condition_variable in C++

Tags: multithreading, thread-safety, thread-synchronization

I'm trying to implement consumer producer using conditional variables, here is some code which is pretty standard:

```
void producer() {
  bool shouldQuit = false;
  while (!shouldQuit) {
    std::unique_lock lk(md);
    std::cout << "p" << threadid << " waiting" << std::endl;
    cv.wait(lk, [] { return processed; });
    processed = false;
    std::cout << "p" << threadid << " finished waiting" << std::endl;
    if (d < 10) {
      data = "p" + std::to_string(threadid) + " " + std::to_string(d);
      std::cout << data << std::endl;
      d++;
      std::cout << "p" << threadid << " unlocking" << std::endl;
      ready = true;
      lk.unlock();
      std::cout << "p" << threadid << " unlocked" << std::endl;
      cv.notify_one();
    } else {
      shouldQuit = true;
    }
  }
}

void consumer() {
  bool shouldQuit = false;
  while (!shouldQuit) {
    std::unique_lock lk(md);
    std::cout << "c" << threadid << " waiting" << std::endl;
    cv.wait(lk, [] { return ready; });
    ready = false;
    std::cout << "c" << threadid << " finished waiting" << std::endl;
    if (data.empty()) {
      shouldQuit = true;
    } else {
      std::cout << "c" << threadid << " < " << data << std::endl;
      processed = true;
    }
    std::cout << "c" << threadid << " unlocking" << std::endl;
    lk.unlock();
    cv.notify_one();
    std::cout << "c" << threadid << " unlocked" << std::endl;
  }
}
```

I use 2 booleans, "ready" on which the consumer waits, and "processed" on which the producer waits.

However the producers hang quickly:

```
prod 0
p0 waiting
p0 finished waiting
p0 0
p0 unlocking
p0 unlocked
p0 waiting
prod 1
p1 waiting
cons 2
c2 waiting
c2 finished waiting
c2 < p0 0
c2 unlocking
c2 unlocked
c2 waiting
p0 finished waiting
p0 1
p0 unlocking
p0 unlocked
p0 waiting
cons 3
c3 waiting
c3 finished waiting
c3 < p0 1
c3 unlocking <--- this should unblock any producer to produce more, but it doesn't :(
c3 unlocked
c3 waiting
```

and I can't figure out why. Any hints appreciated :) Thank you

Comment: did you initialize processed and ready

Comment: Yes, processed=true to have one of the producers started, ready=false.

Comment: Ok so it seems to work correctly (no thread remains blocked) if I change either the producer or consumer notify_one() to notify_all(). However I don't think this makes sense - I think it should work with notify_one().

Comment: If anyone has any simple working code for multiple producer-consumer synchronization, I would love to take a look, I couldn't find anything online.